# How to override a class constant in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, constants

When working with constants, I've always tried to define constants like the following which allows end-users to override their values.

```
if ( ! defined( 'MY_CONST' ) )
    define ( 'MY_CONST', 10 );
```

I've now started to work with classes (OOP) and would like to know if there's a way to define a class constant that will allow the value to be overridden by end-users?

Refs:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php

Comment: You know that in the example you show us you don't overwrite the constant you just define it if it isn't defined?

Comment: Are you asking whether it's possible for end-users to override a class constant or do you want to *allow* for end-users to override it?

Comment: Maybe you should explain what you mean by "end-users". If it's about library with varying states, then a plain variable is often more apt.

Comment: By end-users, I mean users of my code. For example, User A downloads my project to use in their own project. Sorry for not making this clearer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your users are extending your class, they can redefine the constant just fine:

```
class Foo extends Bar {
    const BAZ = 42;
}
```

It doesn't matter whether `Bar` already defines a `BAZ` constant or not. All you have to do in your code is make sure you're referring to the "current classes" constant using late static binding:

```
public function useConst() {
    echo static::BAZ;
}
```

Otherwise, you have the option of doing this:

```
if (!defined('BAZ')) {
    define('BAZ', 42);
}

class Bar {
    const BAZ = BAZ;
}
```

That's not really very elegant though. You should rather be using getters and setters on your class to allow configuration, rather than using constants for this purpose:

```
Bar::setBaz(42);
```

Comment: "You should rather be using getters and setters on your class to allow configuration" I agree... One might use constants for the var names (like with `PDO::setAttribute`): `Bar::setOption(Bar::BAZ, 42)`, depending on what it is youre implementing this may be a good idea or not.

Comment: Indeed. If the content is malleable, it's probably not a *constant*. :o)

Comment: Even though it's the most elegant option, I'm not sure my users would be comfortable extending classes. I think the less elegant option is the most practical in my situation. Thanks for highlighting my available options - appreciated!

Comment: @henrywright In that case, just forget about "class constants". Just use constants as you've used them thus far.

Comment: So for simplicity sake, imagine I have defined a constant like this `define ( 'MY_CONST', 10 );`. Would `MY_CONST` be available to use in my class methods?

Comment: @henrywright Yes, constants are available everywhere globally.

Comment: FWIW, As a potential end user for your code i would prefer no constants set with `define()` class constants are fine, but a settings/configuration object that holds application config values that can then be accessed and injected into your classes or mine is preferable. Especially if this is a library or component and not an application or framework.

Comment: @deceze : In the answer you are violating the principal that says "Constants should remain same and they can not be changed till the end of script. They are simple unchangeable". which constant stand for. If someone wants to override the constants then he can make use of class properties rather than class constants. What do you say about this?

Comment: @user2839497 Well, the constant *doesn’t* change, just different classes may have different values. Which is reasonable for something like Active Record type classes which have something like `UserRecord::TABLE = 'users'`.